# how to merge same valued data frames with different data types in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am having two data frames.

```
df 1:-
x  y  z  
n  1  2.0
m  3  4.0
x: dtype('object')
y: dtype('int64')
z: dtype('float64')


df 2:-
x y z a
n 1 2 h
n 2 1 k
x: dtype('object')
y: dtype('object')
z: dtype('object')
a: dtype('int64')
```

now I want to merge these data frames on x,y,z.

I used the following code, I got an error due to different datatype of the variables.

```
syntax:
df2.merge(df1,on=['x','y','z'],how='left')
```

I don't want to change df2  data types manually.

based on df1 dtypes i have to change the df2 common variables data types.

can anyone help me to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) by [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes)
print (df2.dtypes)
x     object
y      int64
z    float64
a     object
dtype: object
```

---

```
df = df2.astype(df1.dtypes).merge(df1,on=['x','y','z'],how='left')
print (df)
   x  y    z  a
0  n  1  2.0  h
1  n  2  1.0  k
```

Comment: I edited my question, if you don't mind can you check it once.

Comment: @neeraja - with sample data it working nice, check last edit.